# jboss destination queue is in CLOSED state

Tags: jboss, queue

We are using the jboss application server version 4.2.3.

After starting the server, One of the destination queue 'testQueue' bound becomes to CLOSED state.
While checking the logs, the below information was present.

> 2014-01-07 20:55:49,855  INFO [genericEventJmsContainer-1]- Setup of
>   JMS message listener invoker failed for destination
>   'JBossQueue[testQueue]' - trying to recover. Cause: The object is
>   closed javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The object is closed  at
>   org.jboss.jms.client.container.ClosedInterceptor.invoke(ClosedInterceptor.java:159)
>     at
>   org.jboss.aop.advice.PerInstanceInterceptor.invoke(PerInstanceInterceptor.java:105)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientConsumerDelegate$receive_N8299950230150603585.invokeNext(ClientConsumerDelegate$receive_N8299950230150603585.java)    at
>   org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientConsumerDelegate.receive(ClientConsumerDelegate.java)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jms.client.JBossMessageConsumer.receive(JBossMessageConsumer.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jms.connection.CachedMessageConsumer.receive(CachedMessageConsumer.java:74)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveMessage(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:405)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:982)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:974)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:876)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Could anyone kindly provide us with some inputs on the reason why a selected destination becomes to CLOSED state after a certain period of time from the server start time?

Answer (score 0):

It may be the bug https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBESB-1491 which is in version 4.2.1 ,which is fixed version is 4.3.

Please share the JMS configuration you have done for Queue.

Also you can find related topic http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r1/html/ch6.chapt.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.jms.server.destination.QueueService"     name="jboss.esb.quickstart.destination:service=Queue,name=testQueue"    xmbean-dd="xmdesc/Queue-xmbean.xml">    <depends optional-attribute-name="ServerPeer">jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer    </depends>  <depends>jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice</depends>   <attribute name="RedeliveryDelay">1000</attribute>  <attribute name="MaxDeliveryAttempts">15</attribute>    <attribute name="Clustered">true</attribute> </mbean>
```

Above is a sample configuration we make for a Queue destination.

These queues are defined in JBOSS SOA server version 4.3 and being listened by components deployed in JBOSS Application Server version 4.2.3